# Guessing Card Game

Tags: probability, card-games, gambling

Consider a deck with 26 black and 26 red cards. You draw one card at a time and you can choose either guess on whether it is red beforehand or simply observe the result. If the card is red you get $1\$$ and the game ends whenever you decide to guess. What is your strategy to play this game and the expected earnings?

---

I found the question on the web but i am not sure about what it is actually asked.

If it is saying: you can play 1 time only, then I think the best would be to guess whenever the chances are higher than 50% (that is the starting probability) which will happen eventually.

One might ask: what is the maximum expected probability for which we should guess?

Comment: "game ends whenever you decide to guess" - So one can play how many ever times they want?

Comment: No penalty so just play until we run out of cards to get $26

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja The game ends after a guess, so you win at most $1.